# Помощь по серверам

Tags: веб-сервер

Хотелось бы узнать о том, как самому организовать свой web-сервер, что для этого нужно знать, как расчитывать нагрузки, которые может выдержать сервер и подобного рода информация связанная не только с железом, но и с программным обеспечением.

Быть может кто-то может посоветовать книги по данной теме, журналы или сайты?

Заранее спасибо за любого рода информацию!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно определиться с операционной системой, для начала. Нагрузку лучше всего оценивать на уже работающей системе. В данный момент мой сервер работает на рабочей станции обычной, когда-то ставил на выделенный сервер - принципиальной разницы не заметил. Все зависит от того проекта, который должен обслуживать Ваш сервер. Как только определитесь с ОС, так сразу и информацию получите по настройке и прочим премудростям.

Answer (score 0):

А смысл в том чтобы просто иметь свой сервер?

Нагрузки - для каждого сайта свои, что сервер может выдержать, так это на калькуляторе можно посчитать примерные значения.

Не понимаю смысла вопроса. Зачем он тебе нужен, а главное для чего?